# VPN doubt about "encrypting" an IP address

Tags: network, vpn, ip, openvpn

According to [Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-a-vpn)

> **Encryption of your IP address**: The primary job of a VPN is to hide
> your IP address from your ISP and other third parties. This allows you
> to send and receive information online without the risk of anyone but
> you and the VPN provider seeing it.

So, how is it possible that ISP knows where to return packets, then, if the IP headers in packets on lower layer of abstraction are encrypted? Obviously, the VPN server will know the origin IP, but when they want to return the information back, they would have to specify where they are sending it to and at one point, it's the ISP that is handing me the packets back. Their routers on the physical layer need to know the direction, so they would obviously need to know the IP if they want to return the packet back.

Did I miss understand this quote or am I I not seeing something right?

Comment: *"The primary job of a VPN is to hide your IP address from your ISP"* - that does not make any sense. The ISP is the one which assigns the public IP address to you in the first place, so it will definitely know your IP even if no data are transmitted at all.

Comment: That is what I thought as well. This is straight off from Kaspersky's VPN explanation page.

Comment: When quoting things, make sure to include a citation (add the link) Sometimes context changes the meaning of a quote

Comment: This exact sentence is repeated on several places on the internet. It is not clear from me where it originated, but it does not make sense for me.

Comment: Ok its edited. It seems like Kaspersky posted some very questionable things. Not sure if it was for marketing purposes, but this technically doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VPN expert with English as a first language did not write those words. It's wrong and meaningless. But I do understand the gist of what the author meant to say. Your IP is hidden from your target and your traffic is hidden from your ISP.

According to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2020*/https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-a-vpn), this new copy was added some time between Aug-Nov 2020. It looks like it was not properly reviewed... What's interesting is that all instances of this quote in other places start to appear in November 2020.